# Get first N rows from table based on condition - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

table1

```
Type            Attribute           Value       Count
Fruit           Apple               Sweet       1772
Fruit           Apple               Sour        1021
Fruit           Apple               Sweetest    930
Fruit           Apple               Sweetest    930
Fruit           Orange              Sweetest    200
Fruit           Orange              Sour        190
Fruit           Orange              Sweetest    160
Fruit           Orange              Sweetest    140
```

I need the first 3 rows based on type and attribute and count.

So, the output should be:

```
Type            Attribute           Value       Count
Fruit           Apple               Sweet       1772
Fruit           Apple               Sour        1021
Fruit           Apple               Sweetest    930
Fruit           Orange              Sweetest    200
Fruit           Orange              Sour        190
Fruit           Orange              Sweetest    160
```

How can I grab the first 3 rows for each type, attribute, count?

Comment: So for `count` you want the first 3 rows with the highest `count` for a specific set of `type` and `attribute`, right?  Ignore `value`?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers by @GordonLinoff and @LukaszSzozda were based on the original post, and not on the clarification added later by the OP.  The [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c25aa8/1/0) based on original post, using SQL in answer by @Gordon (which is basically identical to answer by @Lukasz as they posted the answers about the same time, before the clarification)  returns 4 rows per `Apple` and 4 rows per `Orange`:

```
FOOD_TYPE  ATTRIBUTE  VALUE     CNT   SEQNUM
Fruit      Apple      Sour      1021  1
Fruit      Apple      Sweet     1772  1
Fruit      Apple      Sweetest   930  1
Fruit      Apple      Sweetest   930  2
Fruit      Orange     Sour       190  1
Fruit      Orange     Sweetest   200  1
Fruit      Orange     Sweetest   160  2
Fruit      Orange     Sweetest   140  3
```

[Modified SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c25aa8/2/0) here

```
select t.*
from (select Food.*,
             row_number() over (partition by food_type, attribute order by cnt desc) as seqnum
      from Food
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

returns the desired result:

```
FOOD_TYPE  ATTRIBUTE  VALUE     CNT    SEQNUM
Fruit      Apple      Sweet     1772   1
Fruit      Apple      Sour      1021   2
Fruit      Apple      Sweetest  930    3
Fruit      Orange     Sweetest  200    1
Fruit      Orange     Sour      190    2
Fruit      Orange     Sweetest  160    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type, attribute, value order by count desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER(PARTIION BY "Type", Attribute ORDER BY "count" DESC) AS rn
  FROM tab t
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3;
```